# Is it possible to make scoped expectations in Google Mock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Is it possible to scope an expectation using Google Mock? In other words, let's say I have the following test fixture:

```
class Fixture : public testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp();

    void TearDown();

    ObjectUnderTest testObject;
    MockObject mock;
};
```

Now, in the `SetUp()` function, I want to allow a mock function call as many times as is necessary during initialisation:

```
void Fixture::SetUp()
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mock.DoStuff(_)).Times(Any());
    testObject.Initialise(mock);
}
```

After this, I want this particular expectation to go out-of-scope and any calls to `DoStuff()` to generate a failure. I can't use `RetiresOnSaturation()` because it will never saturate!

In other words, if I have the following test case:

```
TEST_F(Fixture, DoesWhatItsSupposedTo)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoStuff(Eq(3)));
    testObject.DoSomething(mock);
}
```

I would like this to fail if `DoSomething()` calls `DoStuff(4)` on the mock object. With gmock default behaviour (which is right for most scenarios), it will first check the second expectation that won't match; it will then check the expectation in `SetUp()` that will match and pass.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be really answer to your question, but you can explicitly forbid a call using `.Times(0)`:

```
TEST_F(Fixture, DoesWhatItsSupposedTo)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoStuff(Eq(3)));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoStuff(Ne(3)))
            .Times(0);
    testObject.DoSomething(mock);
}
```

This will expect one call of `DoStuff(3)`and no other calls of `DoStuff()` within this test - any call is first checked against `DoStuff(Ne(3))`. Before the test, any call will still be accepted.

Comment: While you are correct that this will work. This is very tedious when trying to debug a broken test as every fullfilled exception will be printed.
Maybe [VerifyAndClearExpectations](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#forcing-a-verification) will help.